# Multiple select in angular js and php

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have to do a project in angular.js and php (Codeigniter) “show student details”.
Here I have a challenge. First I have to select the class. Once I select the class it will show all the students details in that class. This have one more drop down this will select the sports its multi select drop down

Select Class (5th,6th,7th,8th,9th,10th) in select box we can select only one

Select Sports(Badminton,Swimming,Running race,Shot put,Long jump) select box we can select multiple

By selecting class itself using json i will fetch all the details of student in that class.

details are in different table but i will send a single response with full details.

Selecting sports only little bit tough. 
 table structure of sports

sports_table (sports_id,sports_name) and other table 
sports_student(id,student_id,sports_id)

On select of sports i have to show those who are match with sports_student table without any json request

Comment: And what is your problem, what can't you do? Please show us your javascript and php code what you've tried.

Comment: i dont have any idea to select the students based on multiple values

Comment: You need to use join in your query like this (not tested) `$sql = "SELECT * FROM sports_students "
 . "INNER JOIN sports_table ON sports_table.sports_id = sporst_students.sports.id "
 . "WHERE sports_table.sports_name = 'Badminton' OR sports_table.sports_name = 'Swimming'";`

Comment: ok thanks let me try

Comment: With using IN also I can do this na

Comment: sports_name  IN('badminton','')

Comment: yes, IN is a solution also.